# Deleting and inserting a row in a table?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am following some swift tutorials and I have been noticing that sometimes it's enough to use the array and append/remove but sometimes you have to also add insertrows/deleterows for the table to have the required result and i can't distinguish when and why

```
        tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: I believe task here is your dataSource, when you delete a row from table you should also update your datasource accordingly for tableView to stay in sync.

Comment: Keep in mind to always use the DispatchQueue when working with UI Elements. Especially when you update or refresh them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically removing data from your data source will perform the deletion. In case of showing that deletion happened, you are using delete rows. which will show the delete animation and reload the data source.